# What's the advantage of using method references in this case?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have two variables as follows:

`List<Basket> bigBasket = new ArrayList<>();
 Basket basket = new Basket();`

I wrote the following code to add a relationship between items in `bigBasket` and `basket`:

```
for (Fruit specialFruit : bigBasket.get(0).getFruitInBasket()) {
    for (Fruit fruit : basket.getFruitInBasket()) {
        specialFruit.addRelationship(fruit);
    }
}
```

Now this is all fine but IntelliJ inspected the code and offered to improve it with the using a method reference so I got the following:

```
for (Fruit specialFruit : bigBasket.get(0).getFruitInBasket()) {
   basket.getFruitInBasket().forEach(specialFruit::addRelationship);
}
```

So the above has fewer lines but what is the actual advantage of it? I am not entirely clued up on the benefits of Java 8 features so that's probably why I don't really understand what's happening.

In my opinion, the "improved" version of code is not very readable in the sense of immediately understanding what's happening vs a standard for loop assuming you don't have much knowledge about Java 8 features.

Could someone explain the benefits of the "improved" code vs the standard for loop?

EDIT: Removed incorrect references to lambdas. The code is just using method references - just a lingo mistake on my part!

Comment: Maybe it’s just the method reference which looks unintuitive to you? How about `bigBasket.get(0).getFruitInBasket().forEach(specialFruit -> basket.getFruitInBasket().forEach(fruit -> specialFruit.addRelationship(fruit) ));` ?

Comment: Certainly an idiom cannot be readable to a person not familiar with it, but that's just a truism. The really relevant point is this: which one is more readable to a person equally familiar with *both* idioms? For me, `forEach` construct is much easier because there are less things to check to be positively sure what the snippet does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no advantage in the "improved" code in terms of performance. Both snippets would iterate over the entire `basket.getFruitInBasket()` Collection, and perform the exact same action for each element.

Preferring one way over the other is simply a matter of taste. In my opinion, the Java 8 version expresses the fact that you perform a single action on all elements of the Collection more clearly (assuming you are used to method references).

BTW, there's no lambda expression in your code, just a method reference.